# How can I get name string in array list start with letter T and display name of teacher?

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I get a list has the name of teachers starting with letter "T" in array list java. I want to display a list name of teachers. if the list of teachers is not exit, it will show "There are no teachers has a name starting with letter T".  The program is about abstract and polymorphism.  Here is my code

```
class teacher 
package Tinhdahinh;
public abstract class Teacher {
//Properties
int code;
String name;

//method

public Teacher() {
}

public Teacher(int code, String name) {
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(int code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
// ham hien thi thong tin

void show(){
    System.out.print(this.getCode() + "\t" + this.getName());
}

//Ham abstract tinh luong
abstract double getSalary();
}
```

class interface manage method

```
@Override
public void countNameStarByt(ArrayList<Teacher> lst) {
  int count = 0;
  for (Teacher teacher : lst) {
        if(teacher.getName().startsWith("T")){
            count++;
           // teacher.show();
        }
             if(count > 0){
                 System.out.println(count);
                teacher.show(); 
    }
        else{
            System.out.println("No teacher has name starting with letter 
'T'.");
             break;
            }

  }
    //System.out.println("");
}

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Quanly Q = new Quanly();
    ArrayList<Teacher> lst = new ArrayList();
    Q.inputList(lst, 3);
   System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Is there any teachers has name starting with letter 
'T': ");
    Q.countNameStarByt(lst);
}
}
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Please dont just put code here, and requirements. Tell us what is not working. And hint: use ` new ArrayList<>()` .. without the `<>`you are creating a raw type, which gives an '*important** compiler warning!

Comment: What is exactly wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of `count` is wrong. If count becomes greater than zero, the code will print out every `Teacher` object irrespective of whether their name starts with `T` or not. If the `count` is zero, then the loop will get terminated even though you have valid objects in the list.

Try:

```
@Override
public void countNameStarByt(ArrayList<Teacher> lst) {
   int count = 0;
   for (Teacher teacher: lst) {
      if(teacher.getName().startsWith("T")){
        count++;
        teacher.show();
      } 
   }
   if (count == 0) {
      System.out.println("No teacher has name starting with letter 'T'.");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem that i can see in your code, is in else part you have written break statement. So, in first iteration if list is not found then control will be in else and will break the loop.

this can work for you

```
for (Teacher teacher : lst) {
    if(teacher.getName().startsWith("T")){
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
        teacher.show();
    }
}
if(count==0){
    System.out.println("Teacher not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (Teacher teacher: lst) {
if(teacher.getName().startsWith("T")){
    count++;
    System.out.println(count);
    teacher.show();
   }
 }
    if(count==0){
    System.out.println("Teacher not found");
}
```